# Is it possible in Debezium to configure table_name => kafka topic mapping?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I've read http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/ but I could not find any info about whether debezium can be configured so that changes from 2 (or more) tables could be written to the same, single kafka topic? It seems to me that it is always 1 table -> 1 topic.

Comment: It seems to be possible http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/topic-routing/ but I am not exactly sure whether it requires the schema in 2 tables to be exactly the same or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [Single Message Transforms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms), per [the link](http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/topic-routing/) you identified. You can use regular expressions (regex) to map the tables to the topic required. Both `io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter` or `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter` should do the trick. There's an example of the latter [in this post here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/):

```
"transforms":"dropPrefix",  
"transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",  
"transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"DC1-TEST-(.*)",  
"transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1"
```

Comment: `ByLogicalTableRouter` lets you enrich the primary key which may be useful when having events from multiple tables in one topic. On the question in the comment above, its original use case was for sharded tables, but it should work for tables with different schemas, too.