# Capture all database tables to one Kafka topic with Debezium

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, cdc, debezium

How can I configure Debezium to publish all tables in a database to a single Kafka topic?

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to do this since you would have different schemas for each table and there's no disadvantages to having many topics in Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 One scenario could be where you have multiple tenants in your db dynamically creating their own types (tables) as part of their business model definition. Managing the topics in this case could become unwieldy. You might choose to group tenant data and have a topic per tenant for example.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Debezium writes out a topic per database+table

You might want to look at the documentation on [topic routing](https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/topic-routing/), though

> Debezium enables you to re-route the emitted change before the message reaches the converter using a single message transformation, or SMT. The SMT provided by Debezium enables you to rewrite the topic and the key according to a regular expression and a replacement pattern, configurable per instance of Debezium.

So you can try something like

```
transforms=Combine
transforms.Combine.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.Combine.topic.regex=(.*)
transforms.Combine.topic.replacement=all_tables
```

There are other SMT examples you can find on Kafka Connect documentation section, and I think the `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter` is one worth trying

Comment: Should I do the above changes in `connect-file-source.properties` in Kafka connect?

Comment: No, these are Debezium properties

Comment: Thanks. But I tried the above it did not work, but this post answer worked [Is it possible in Debezium to configure table_name => kafka topic mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742810/is-it-possible-in-debezium-to-configure-table-name-kafka-topic-mapping)